# Create associative array containing values of original array as both keys and values

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a function for creating an associative array with the values of the original array as both key and value? I already looked at array_flip and array_keys but they don't seem to be able to create this.

Say i have this array:

```
[0 => 'foo', 1 => 'bar']
```

And i want to convert this to:

```
[foo => 'foo', bar => 'bar']
```

Obviously this would work, but i'm looking for a function.

```
$array = [];
foreach ($original_Arr as $key => $value) {$choices[$value] = $value;}
```

Comment: `array_combine(array_values($arr), array_values($arr))`

Comment: As the array is a plain array, you can miss out the `array_values()` part and use `array_combine($arr, $arr)`

Comment: @NigelRen Actually the documentation _Creates an array by using the **values** from the keys array as keys and the **values** from the values array as the corresponding values._ So it will actually work also with an associative array and not just plain one

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [`array_combine`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to create the result.

> array_combine ( array $keys , array $values ) : array
>
> Creates an array by using the values from the keys array as keys and the values from the values array as the corresponding values.

Pass your original array as both the **keys** and **values** to create the desired outcome

```php
<?php
    
    $array = [];
    $array[0] = 'foo';
    $array[1] = 'bar';
    
    $res = array_combine($array, $array);
    print_r($res);
```

```
Array
(
    [foo] => foo
    [bar] => bar
)
```

[Try it online!](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/14ea6259f680a4a995a393c92bb901f731fe38d1)

---

The above solution **does not work** when applying **multidimensional arrays**.

You'll need to ['flatten'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array) the array before passing to `array_combine` to get the desired values;

```php
<?php
    
    $array = [];
    $array[] = 'foo';
    $array[1] = 'bar';
    $array[2] = [ 'foobar', 'barfoo' ];
    
    $values = flat($array);
    
    $res = array_combine($values, $values);
    print_r($res);
    
    function flat($array) {
        $values = [];
        array_walk_recursive($array, function($a) use (&$values) { $values[] = $a; });
        return $values;
    }
```

```
Array
(
    [foo] => foo
    [bar] => bar
    [foobar] => foobar
    [barfoo] => barfoo
)
```